# My suffix is infantile paralysis

Tags: riddle, word, poetry

> My prefix is a parking lot for ________, 
>    My suffix is infantile paralysis with a _______. 
>  
>    If you remove the letter ____ from my whole, 
>    You get the anagram of the property of water.

What word am I?

Comment: form your whole or from your whole?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The word is

> PORTFOLIO

My prefix is a parking lot for

> Boats => PORT,

My suffix is infantile paralysis with a

> P => P+olio = POLIO

If you remove the letter ____ form my whole,

> remove the letter T

You get the anagram of the property of water.

> OILPROOF. Of course, oil and water don't mix!

Comment: how do you get from rot13(cbyvb gb sbyvb?)

Comment: @SteveV rot13(byvb vf gur fhssvk, abg sbyvb. Nqq C gb byvb)

Comment: I know it's been almost three months, but I still don't understand the second line. Shouldn't "with a" be "without a" instead?